# error occured while executing the javascript code in java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I want to execute javascript code in java. So I Wrote the code as shown in below. But during execution it fails at middle line. saying error as 'missing ; before statement '.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

String g=(String) js.executeScript("var r = confirm('r u ready');"+"if(r==true) { Var b='ok'; } return b;");

System.out.println(g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to block the execution until the dilog is closed, then you should use executeAsyncScript instead of executeScript.

Here is an example to display a confirm dialog and wait for someone to close it:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");

Boolean confirm = (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(
  "var callback = arguments[0]; setTimeout(function(){ " +
  "  callback(window.confirm('Are you ready?'));       " +
  "}, 1);");
```

And another one to display a prompt dialog and wait for someone to type some text and close it:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");

// display a confirm dialog and waits for someone to type some text
String prompt = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(
  "var callback = arguments[0]; setTimeout(function(){ " +
  "  callback(window.prompt('Give me some text!'));    " +
  "}, 1);");

// display the text typed by the user
System.out.println(prompt);
```

Comment: Thank you brother, you correctly guessed what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the variable declaration, replace `Var` with `var`:

```
String g=(String) js.executeScript("var r = confirm('r u ready'); var b; if(r == true) { b='ok'; } return b;");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"(function() {var r,b; r = confirm('r u ready'); if(r == true) { b='ok'; } return b;})()"
```

Comment: I expected the above statement returns output string as 'ok'. But it returns outpur as 'r u ready'. So how can I get output as 'ok'

Comment: Tip: to accelerate debugging run `executeScript` string inside the browser console))